# jQuery.textcomplete need to recognise space in value

Tags: jquery, regex

I am using the following plugin as a text complete: http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/

Currently I can type @ and it display my list of values which then highlight using the overlay when selected (see Use with jQuery.overlay section on website). What you cannot do is have a space in a value so "@My value" would only highlight "@my". I would like the whole value to highight and recognise the spaces.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Below is the function I use:

```
function SMSTextArea() {
    $('.intellisense').textcomplete(
        [
            { // Intrinsics
                mentions: pullArrIntrinsicsVar(),
                match: /\B@i(\w*)$/,
                search: function (term, callback) {
                    callback($.map(this.mentions, function (mention) {
                        return mention.indexOf(term) === 0 ? mention : null;
                    }));
                },
                index: 1,
                replace: function (mention) {
                    return '@i' + mention + ' ';
                }
            }

        ], 
        { appendTo: 'body' }
    ).overlay(
        [
            {
                match: /\B@i\w+/g,                       // Intrinsics
                css: {
                    'background-color': '#DDFFD1'
                }
            }   
        ]
    );
```

Comment: can you prepare a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

please try to change the match parameter

```
/\B@i(\w*)$/
```

with this:

```
/@\b([a-z0-9\s]{1,})$/
```